# LinkToken with account filters - assets/investment/brokerage - not working

Tags: plaid

I am currently trying to retrieve the link token using a curl command in my terminal. I ultimately want to obtain the user's investment data in my app so I decided to use the assets product with account_filter of investment and subtype brokerage. However, this is not working.

Here is the request I am using (minus the IDs):

```
curl -X POST https://sandbox.plaid.com/link/token/create -H 'Content-Type: application/json' -d '{
  "client_id": "...",
  "secret": "...",
  "user": {    "client_user_id": "unique-per-user"
  },
  "client_name": "...",
  "products": ["assets"],
  "country_codes": ["US"],
  "language": "en",
  "redirect_uri": "...",
  "account_filters": {
      "investment": {
          "account_subtypes": ["brokerage"]
      }
  }
}'
```

I then get the error:

```
{
  "display_message": null,
  "documentation_url": "https://plaid.com/docs/#create-link-token",
  "error_code": "INVALID_FIELD",
  "error_message": "account_filters must be nonempty Map\u003caccount type, Map\u003c\"account_subtypes\", Array\u003caccount subtype\u003e\u003e\u003e where account type and account subtype are strings. There must also be at least 1 valid product and account type combination.",
  "error_type": "INVALID_REQUEST",
  "request_id": "...",
  "suggested_action": null
}%
```

Answer (score 1):

UPDATE: I've confirmed with the Assets team that appears to be a bug / unintended behavior, they are looking into it.

I'm not entirely sure why, but it does seem like the Assets product does not support using account filters for anything other than depository accounts. Note that the Assets API is designed for lending use cases and gets a snapshot of a single point in time of a user's account balances and transactions. If you're looking to understand someone's investments, you in most cases probably want to use the Plaid Investments API, which allows you to view what a user is invested in, has automatic account filtering for investments accounts built in, and will keep you up-to-date with a user's current investments.